# React Native Execution failed for AarResourcesComplierTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

First of all, hello everyone.
I'm trying to run my React Native application on Android, but I'm getting the following error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform appcompat-1.1.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e6707299ed28953a363648ed5c9f1095/transformed/appcompat-1.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform appcompat-1.1.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e6707299ed28953a363648ed5c9f1095/transformed/appcompat-1.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.6.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7e8c74aa555cf02a76fe5acdd27f9f62/transformed/jetified-play-services-base-17.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.6.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7e8c74aa555cf02a76fe5acdd27f9f62/transformed/jetified-play-services-base-17.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c7276f9386c9f50bd228bf11710f82/transformed/core-1.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c7276f9386c9f50bd228bf11710f82/transformed/core-1.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c7276f9386c9f50bd228bf11710f82/transformed/core-1.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c7276f9386c9f50bd228bf11710f82/transformed/core-1.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c7276f9386c9f50bd228bf11710f82/transformed/core-1.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c7276f9386c9f50bd228bf11710f82/transformed/core-1.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c7276f9386c9f50bd228bf11710f82/transformed/core-1.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c7276f9386c9f50bd228bf11710f82/transformed/core-1.6.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.2-7147631-osx Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e8c7276f9386c9f50bd228bf11710f82/transformed/core-1.6.0.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 53s

```
at makeError (/Users/[USER_NAME]/Desktop/[PROJECT_NAME]/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /Users/[USER_NAME]/Desktop/[PROJECT_NAME]/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/[USER_NAME]/Desktop/[PROJECT_NAME]/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/[USER_NAME]/Desktop/[PROJECT_NAME]/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

My android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.1.6352462"
        kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }

    def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
}
```

My android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);

android {
    packagingOptions {
      pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
      pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    lintOptions { 
  checkReleaseBuilds false 
}


    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "APPLICATION.ID"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 50
        versionName "1.1.15"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    implementation 'com.sunmi:printerlibrary:1.0.13'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'

    compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')

    implementation project(':react-native-mmkv')
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6+'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'; applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

I am running it on my own Mac with an M2 processor, but when my friend tries to run the same application on his M1 computer, he encounters this error. I've tried installing the necessary packages with the same versions and even formatting and reinstalling the computer, but I haven't been able to succeed. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help.